# Is the Star Wars Holiday Special part of Disney's SW canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

If you are reading this, you are probably twitching already, but I think it qualifies as a fair question because there is a lot of uncertainty about what the Disney Story Group will keep from earlier Star Wars material.

Despite how bad it is, the Holiday Special was accepted as canon (I do not know what level). So... Is there any official information on whetherany parts of it may be reincorporated in the new canon?

Comment: Will X do Y? Who knows? This is off-topic.

Comment: Let's keep it [open] for a little while, someone might have some extra info somewhere. Also, this can be re-worded to "Is there any information..." or "are there plans in place...?" etc. Otherwise as @AndresF. says, it is [off-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because we don't know what someone will do until they do it.

Comment: Although I know various people cribbed from it over the years (Boba Fett, for instance), I would think something becomes non-canon once its creator decides he wants every copy found and burned...

Comment: Since Disney already made a statement on what was kept as canon and what was not, there is nothing indicating that they would suddenly reverse and switch the canon levels of old materials like the Holiday Special.

Comment: @phantom42 - Exactly this. Although they may choose to incorporate elements of EU properties into the new movies, their statement was explicit that only the 6 movies, Clone Wars TV Series and Movie and Rebels TV Series (and tie-in books) would be canon from now on.

Comment: @Mooz - if someone has inside information and is willing to break the NDA, they can flag for moderator to reopen or post a request on Meta

Comment: @Gaius - It is indeed a dupe. Don't forget you can press the "close" button to vote to close as a duplicate. You even get badges for it.